# All caps text is crammed in lstlisting

Tags: fonts, spacing, listings

I'm using `lstlisting` for command line documentation. The problem is that anything written in all CAPS is poorly spaced inside `lstlisting` but normal outside of it.
I observed the same issue with multiple fonts so the problem is likely in `lstlisting`.

Edit: The minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
some lowercase text.
SOME CRAMMED UPPERCASE TEXT
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`listings` uses a fixed width independent (more or less) of the font to get aligned output. The options to control this behaviour are `basewidth` (the width used), `columns` and `flexiblecolumns` (to (de)activate the feature all together).

So either use `basewidth=<some-length-big-enough>` or `flexiblecolumns=true` with `columns = flexible` or `columns = fullflexible` to work around this (whatever fits your needs better).